# How can I remove my remote lockout on my front suspension fork?

Tags: suspension, front, lockout

I have a trek dual sport 4 and I always keep the front fork unlocked.  Can I remove the remote lockout?  I somehow invariably hit the switch and find out next I take an impact with being and old guy with arthritis in the wrist and hand is never pleasant.

Comment: Can you reorganise your bar, to move the remote lockout switch further away from your hands?  Slide it over a bit so its harder to hit, or rotate it a little so the lever is harder to find accidentially ?

Answer (score 3):

There are some forks where removing it completely doesn't work because the default (no cable pull) mode is locked. If yours isn't like that, then yes you can remove it completely without issue.

Most forks with remote lockout also have a manually switchable top cap or damper assembly available that can replace the remote lockout top cap. That is easy for a shop that deals with any kind of suspension work to source and install. Doing it DIY will require figuring out the right part and potentially may take a special tool.

EDIT: MaplePanda makes an excellent point that if you did have a fork where the default (no cable pull) mode is locked out, you can easily just take a small piece of cable, put the head where the end of the housing would usually go, and permanently unlock the fork that way.

Comment: One can get by a locked default by just hooking up a short piece of cable permanently. Isn’t it usually a whole new damper assembly, not just the top cap?

Comment: @MaplePanda Fox utilize different top cap assemblies for remote and manual actuated controls.  The rest of the damper assembly remains the same.